# Flask App returning a value of None when trying to print console output to webpage

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Python program called `main.py`.

It looks like this :

```
import stuff

def execute():
   print("some stuff")
```

Now, I wanted the output of this file to be displayed on a webpage

So, I made a Flask File :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import main

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def script_output():
    output = main.execute()
    return render_template('template_name.html',output=output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this is the `template_name.html` file :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Trial</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>{{ output }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the Webpage sowing a value of None and still printing to the Python console? How do I correct it /

Answer (score 1):

The execute function doesn't return anything. Since it doesn't, the variable `output` will get set to `None`

**main.py**

```py
import stuff

def execute():
   print("some stuff")
   return "some stuff"
```

Comment: Thanks , I got it but there are multiple print lines that I need to execute in the function. How do I proceed ?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to show on the UI. You want to show some table or some other logic involving forms and buttons.

Comment: I would say a list or a dict or a list of dict items. Templating frameworks (eg jinja2) allow you to easily access the values of these, in the same way python allows you to access them. Look at a tutorial for jinja2 to see how you can do this...